# How to integrate Qt/C++-Framework in a native Swift 5 iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, qt, qt6

I am very new to Qt and finding myself having trouble to integrate a Qt 6-Project in my native Swift 5 iOS Project as I don't find any recent information on this topic online.

The Qt project is written in C++/Qt and is using Qt-Classes like QString, QTimer etc. (no UI Components, just computing stuff).
The Swift project is a native iOS application using UIKit, not using any Qt sources right now.

What would be the needed steps to integrate this C++/Qt project as a framework in my Swift project? I know that there should be no trouble integrating a pure C++ framework, but what needs to be done for a C++/Qt framework? Do I have to write wrappers for every used Qt-Class or are there other ways?

Comment: 1. Create a simple proof-of-concept std-only C++ library to integrate with matching POC swift code. 2. Create a simple POC Qt library (handling the data types you need in from the real Qt code) and matching  Swift POC. 3. Return to your original problem. And by "simple" I mean as simple as possible.